# Help with question - 6 downvotes, no comments

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I got six downvotes in a short time for [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916324/ldap-query-for-active-directory-get-adcomputer-in-powershell) which I deleted, and  have now re-opened

[image]

Can I ask for advice on what might be wrong?

I had asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895088/searching-for-several-operating-systems-with-get-adcomputer-using-ldap-filter) previously , but it was apparently not clear enough, and I was advised to open a new one (in the comments to his answer by Vivek-Kumar-Singh) ..

So can I ask for some advice on why my question is so poorly received?

Comment: I up vote your question.

Comment: @Shree: thanks Shree, but I cannot for the life of me work out why it' so poorly recieved - I have done lot's of googling, and tried different things, approaches

Comment: I even think the advice you got is not good as you basically asked a duplicate. Above that the answer on your previous question makes no sense to me. Not sure why that got 2 up votes.

Comment: I agree, and have deleted the question

Comment: The downvotes might be because the question basically is: "I want all PCs with either X **or** Y" but when I ask for "Give me all PCs with X **and** Y" the result is empty. That makes it look there is either a lack of understanding of logical operators or op didn't read the documentation to find out what & in LDAP does.

Comment: @BDL: Thanks, I have deleted the question, after looking harder for the LDAP logical operators

Comment: FWIW two quick link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx (you'll have to read carefully for the OR syntax, but it's there) and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYJ99_8.5.0/admin-system/rbug_ldapfltrxprns.html

Comment: I am literally in the exact same boat. I posted a question yesterday and it got 6 downvotes within 12 minutes of being posted. I could only guess what the issue was because nobody left a single comment nor voted to close, so I tried editing the question to make it better, and now I doubt anyone's going to look at it even if they come across it somewhere because of the negative score.

Comment: @Shree That's not useful. 6 people think that's bad, and assume the question is truly bad, the OP won't know how to improve then. They may get positive score for this question but what about next questions...?

Comment: The issue with SO is that, there are too many people who doesn't care about improving the question, leaving a comment in such cases is wasteful. After a while you get bored. (temporary solution: leave a "I'm welcome to any constructive feedback" comment?)

Comment: Nothing is wrong, except perhaps a small component of obviousness about the and-versus-or issue, but you would have to dig a bit deep to even spot that. It is to be wondered whether there are really 6 people on SO who know anything about LDAP filters at all, let alone enough to comprise 6 downvoters. More likely, 6 idiots downvoted your question, which only means 6 people who know less about it than you do. These are the Purple Hearts of Stack Overflow: as Lee Marvin said, 'a wound stripe'. Wear with pride.

Comment: Since you removed the original question, this question is of no use to anyone. Please consider making this question a helpful example for others, or removing this question as well.

Comment: @SeinopSys: you are literally using the word "literally" wrong `:)` But on the plus side, I can't find anything spectacularly wrong with that question of yours. Shortening it may have been a good choice.

Comment: @valid: I have added the image of the deleted question for users with <10,000 rep ... so now this question will probably start getting downvotes :)

Comment: @SeinopSys:  to me your questions seems like a good one... in topic, no duplicates...

Comment: Getting to -6 in a hurry on such a question with such small [tag] communities is quite unusual.   We can't see the voting pattern anymore because it was deleted.  This smells like targeted voting, if it is then it is not unlikely to happen again.  Be sure to alert a moderator when it does.

Comment: @HansPassant: with the *Meta* effect I got **two upvotes**, but if it'll help I can `undelete` it temporarily so you can check it?

Comment: @user202729 FYI, I consider people posting, "I'm welcome to any constructive feedback" to be a very strong signal that said person is not in fact welcome to constructive feedback, and is more likely than someone who said nothing to respond poorly to critiques to the post.  Even if you are being sincere, too many people say as much to bait downvoters into outing themselves, and they've poisoned the well, as it were.

Comment: @Servy "they've poisoned the well" Too bad.

Comment: I'm only guessing at it, it is best if a moderator sees it.  They can see more than we can.  Don't hesitate to alert them about this deleted question, I'd recommend something like "Very unusual voting pattern, could you please investigate for a possible targeted voting issue".

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks I'll do that ... for some reason I thought you were a mod or still a mod :)

Comment: @OurManinBananas You don't even need to undelete; deleted posts can be flagged.

Comment: so now the *Meta effect* has balanced out the votes, 7 up, 7 down...I think I will answer it...

Comment: so I have no answered the question while the flag is pending...

Comment: You have my sympathy. I think downvoting a question (or for that matter, an answer) without explanation is a disgusting habit and should be banned. It's like spitting in someone's face.

Comment: @MichaelKay: your strong description of downvoting without comment is not a widely shared view amongst other Meta readers. Downvoting is just a communication, and the predominant view here (and amongst mods, I suspect) is that there is no moral or social code to comment when one downvotes (and there is certainly no rule of that kind either). I think it is "nice" for people to do so, but that's as far as it goes. We encourage people to take downvotes/criticism well here, and neither are reasonably comparable to a physical assault.

Comment: Odd that you should tell me that most people disagree with me, but don't make any effort to tell me why they disagree with me. That's precisely what I'm complaining about. It's not useful to know that people disagree with you unless you know why. It's feedback to which you don't know how to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the downvotes came quite rapidly after each other, there can be a number of causes.

1. You are the victim of targeted downvoting. Maybe some users, or a user with multiple accounts, doesn't like you and they decided to downvote you massively. However, this seems unlikely to me.
2. Your question in a niche tag has been seen by active members in the tag, and they found the question really doesn't belong here. What their argument is can only be guessed, but as you found out thanks to comments, you just made a very obvious typo.

If you would reflect this case to my most active tag, the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, someone posting a question where they switched something basic as an AND and OR shouldn't expect too much sympathy: I guess such questions will be downvoted into oblivion, closed and deleted. It is strange though that users downvoted, but didn't vote to close in your case.

If that was indeed the case, I don't say I agree, but it might give some insight in what happened.

Comment: My experience in the C# tag is actually that there will be three answers all explaining that you have to use OR instead, and all of those will be at least at +2… >_<"

Comment: True, but the Q will go down quickly. Sometimes also due to the three persons posting an answer. @poke

Comment: thanks Patrick, much appreciated...

Comment: this issue of mine was also a fundamental lack of knowledge about `LDAP queries` so I am ambivalent about the whole thing!