# What should I do if I suspect voting with multiple accounts?

Tags: discussion, voting, voting-fraud

I recently stumbled upon [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49919999/1983772) which I thought to be legitimate, but it had a score of -6 with only 6 views and no comments. Inspecting OP's reputation changes shows 6 downvotes within 40 seconds with 5-10s intervals between them. Well, that might be just a terrible question getting its fair share of downvotes.

After I commented on the post, my latest question in a low-traffic tag was suddenly downvoted in a similar manner, which strikes me as rather odd. I might be overly paranoid, but this looks like voting abuse to me.

The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) and [other posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes) on Meta mention an automated system to detect serial voting, but do not seem to indicate any measures against other kinds of voting abuse. It seems that you should [flag suspected multiple accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260430/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-user-with-multiple-accounts-and-what-action-will), but in this case, where would I even raise that flag?

What do I do in this situation, flag the original post, contact the support, do nothing?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention and explain the situation with as much detail as you can.

Comment: Yes, these are fraudulent votes.  On yours as well.  You'd have to somewhat admire such a user's dedication, managing 6 accounts and getting them all to vote in less than a minute can't be that easy.  Probably takes a bot.   Odd that they have not been reversed yet, that might be a feature.  By all means get a mod involved, fraud like this is quite evil.

Comment: When you suspect voting fraud, use a custom flag on the post affected.

Comment: Here's another report about a [possibly related case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366298/random-down-votes-to-question-today-under-bash-tag) with 6 downvoted within moments of posting.

Comment: ***author of the question speaking here***, even though this is not a *shiny question*, IMHO, I think it is a fair one. If not, I deserve to know why is it not the case. Maybe it should be in another Q&A . But even so, the lack of feedback is worrysome.

Comment: @toto_tico The mods are probably on the case now. The question seems OK to me. One _could_ argue that it's Primarily Opinion Based, but one should first consider that Apple can be quite strict about usability, and IIRC _has_ some authoritive guidance about it. Besides, that would not be a reason for downvotes, only for a Close Vote.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think SO can detect such serial downvoting automatically.

Comment: What is the objective/motive of such serial downvoting, (assuming that's what it is)?  I don't disagree that it's evil, but why do it?

Comment: [Maybe related too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366242/help-with-question-6-downvotes-no-comments)? (that one was worse, may be related or not)

Comment: @MartinJames Why not ask the downvoter? Maybe they think that having the OP get -12 rep hurts the OP?

Comment: Oh look, suddenly I got some downvotes on my SO questions too! Not 6 though... downvoter isn't trying hard enough :-D

Comment: @toto_tico One major reason that voting flags are slow is that mods cannot view who voted (they only have some tools to help identify it). Only a CM or SO Dev can see the actual votes. So mods might have to escalate this

Comment: @toto_tico while your case here is different because of the suspected fraudulent voting, it does seem you are annoyed by the lack of feedback via comments on the votes.  Downvoting without comments happens frequently for various reasons.  In fact, requiring comments with downvotes is a comment feature request that is usually downvoted.  [Suggested reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s)

Comment: @toto_tico Have you made any enemies recently? ;-)

Comment: @user202729 Yes, it can. It detects more than it auto-reverts I think, which means that it's hard to impossible to work out the thresholds for detection. (Which I find amusing; there are not actually thresholds as such -- there's just a lot of moderator stuff to deal with so it takes a while to get to some things.)

Comment: Most probably one of the mods itself doing it. :D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> What do I do in this situation, flag the original post, contact the
>   support, do nothing?

I've been in multiple situations where there was nothing tangible on the surface (like spam or an abusive post), but there was definitely something rotten happening under the covers.

In times like this, I've *always* found it helpful to just raise a custom flag on the post where you came across such malicious behaviour and explain the situation. Explain with as much detail as you can, but make it as clear and as concise as possible. It may be good to include screenshots where you think it'd help. Consider using an image hosting site like [puush](https://puush.me), [imgur](https://imgur.com), or [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) to do so (puush URLs are extremely short; if you find yourself needing to save characters, that would be a good choice. Even otherwise, there's always URL shorteners).

Make sure your explanation can fit within the character limit. However, I've found myself running out of space quite often, in which case it is O.K. to raise a second flag and continue (as long as you make the thread of continuity clear to the moderators).

For reference, if you have a grievance against a particular user for multiple offences, or for something worse (like harassment, or an abusive profile picture), then it really doesn't matter *where* the flag is raised, as long as you make a clear case against said user/behaviour. You should, however, err on the side of raising the flag *most relevant* to the offence you're reporting.

---

[Some closure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366304/4909087) for interested parties -

> This situation has been taken care of. This and the two similar
>   questions were all the result of a single bad actor which was running
>   a ring of accounts, voting for each other and downvoting other users
>   all at once. The socks have all been deleted and the downvotes
>   reversed in the process.

Comment: Agreed. Maybe superfluous, but... how about adding that the mod flag was best raised on a post related to the offense (either as victim or as perpetrator)? In case of serial voting, on an affected post. In case of an offensive username, on a post by that user. Etc.

Comment: I ended up raising a flag for moderator attention, which was escalated to CMs. The post scores and the reputation of affected users have been amended with "[user was removed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed)". Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can upload images on StackOverflow itself, no need for a third party.

Comment: @Cœur where would I upload an image I want to share in a custom flag?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ [anywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz0tH.png)