# Abnormal down-votes to question today under bash tag

Tags: support, status-completed, downvotes

Noticed this couple of times today, I'm seeing up to 6 down-votes on a question within a few minutes of original posting. Attached below is a capture of a 2nd instance, which has about 6 down-votes with 5 views. Surprisingly the same user has commented in both these posts. Not sure if this is some issue today.

The other question being - [adding alias in a file and run from cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939240/adding-alias-in-a-file-and-run-from-cygwin)

[image]

Comment: Six downvotes? I wonder if it is [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366288/what-should-i-do-if-i-suspect-voting-with-multiple-accounts)....

Comment: Yea, this is starting to look like a voting ring.

Comment: viewed 5 times = downvoted 6 times ? ... a ghost visitor ?

Comment: This is not "random". Consider editing your title...?

Comment: Now that you folks mention it, the votes [on this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49940351/2751851) also look weird to me. (Note there are also *six* downvotes as of now.)

Comment: @TemaniAfif views are heavily cached (unlike votes) so these minor discrepancies are okay. That said per my observations main point of this post, about voting anomalies, looks worth a closer attention. I observe somewhat strange, unusual negative question scores since yesterday

Comment: @yivi: [also related...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366242/2564301) – no wait, it is not just "related" but the exact same thing! *And* mentioned to happen on yet another question in a comment therein (by someone who was "literally in the same boat", which can be interpreted as "yeah, they were on a cruise together").

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366288/4909087), and as it turns out, on the same issue.

Comment: Both of these HOT META POSTS are about the same six downvotes...

Comment: Terrible question.  I'd downvote it six times if I could!  That gives me an idea...

Comment: @undefined I've added the completed tag so this won't be eligible to be pulled in future updates. There's not a lot of reason for this to attract a bunch of community eyeballs anyways.

Comment: @animuson just making a joke.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This situation has been taken care of. This and the two similar questions were all the result of a single bad actor which was running a ring of accounts, voting for each other and downvoting other users all at once. The socks have all been deleted and the downvotes reversed in the process.

Comment: The kind of action I was hoping for: swift and merciless. Would it make sense to close "the two similar questions" as duplicates of this one? Just to indicate that the issues are related and to keep any discussion in one place (for whatever it's still worth discussing on)?

Comment: And I thought it was my question that was genuinely this bad. Glad that wasn't the case.

Comment: Just happened to me and I also wondered if my question was that bad that it deserved to be down voted that much (i.e. -7) and no comment as to why! Got one of my colleague to review it to be sure and it was fine and neither one of us could understand why such down votes until I got contacted by SO. Why on earth are there people out there down voting questions just for the sake of it???

Comment: @Thierry because people use reputation for stuff that wasn't meant to, like considering if the candidate should be selected instead of others, because prestige, etc.